# XCode Clang Format extension not working Xcode 12.3 MacOS Big Sur

Tags: xcode, xcode12, clang-format, macos-big-sur

I upgraded to mac os big sur and XCode 12.3. Earlier I was using XCodeClangFormat extension to format my C++ files. But now this extension is not getting recognized. When I open the extension I don't see it in XCode in the Editor menu. I have already checked that the XCodeClangFormat extension is enabled in the **System Preferences -> Extensions** option for XCode Editor.

Anyone else facing this issue? Can you please suggest a solution for it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try renaming Xcode? That’s apparently a solution on their Github page.. 

Comment: can you provide the link to the solution. I did not understand what do you mean by renaming Xcode?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat/issues/53

Answer (score 2):

Another way to use clang-format is by using automator. (Credits to the original author https://www.jianshu.com/p/1385ab726fc1)

- Step 1: install clang-format (I used Homebrew), as Anticro have pointed out.
- Step 2: Open automator and search for **Run Shell Script**
- Step 3: Enter this script:

```
export PATH = WHERE_YOUR_CLANG_FORMAT_IS_INSTALLED
clang-format
```

- Step 4: Make sure **Output replaces selected text** is checked, **Workflow receives current** is **text**, and in **Xcode**
- Step 5: Save the quick action with the name you want, ex. clang-format
- Step 6: You can put your own configuration for ".clang-format" inside the folder where you installed clang-format.

Now you should be able to select the code and right click for Services -> clang-format (or the name you saved for the quick action)

You can also add shortcuts for the quick action in Keyboard Preferences.

Hope this helps! :D I just love this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have Xcode 12.4 and the source code formatter appears to be a priced product. If you click **Xcode->Xcode Extensions**, it takes you to App Store. There you will find **Xformat** priced at INR 269. Frankly, I didn't attempt to use this. My favorite is **astyle** since my Linux days dating back to more than two decades.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. The extension no longer seems to run. But it is not that bad at all. Since a while ago, I started using a script that would reformat my entire project before I commit.

**<Edit>**
I just need to have Homebrew installed, so I can download clang-format by `brew install clang-format` (Ref: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/clang-format)
**</Edit>**

It runs on double-click and I also integrated it to my git commit/pull/push script.

**<Better Script>**:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd `dirname $0`

if [ -z $(which clang-format) ] ; then
  echo "clang-format not found."
  echo "Install Homebrew, then:"
  echo "brew install clang-format"
  echo ""
  echo "Aborting."
  exit
fi

find . -name *.[h,m] | while read _fmt_f; do
clang-format -i --style=file $_fmt_f
done;
```

**<Old Script>**:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd `dirname $0`

# find files
find . -name *.h > _fmt_files.txt
find . -name *.m >> _fmt_files.txt

# run formatter
while read _fmt_f; do
clang-format -i --style=file $_fmt_f
done <_fmt_files.txt

# make clean
rm _fmt_files.txt
```

In the folder where you run this script, you must place the style-file with name '.clang-format'. Its content should be familiar to you.

If you use a predefined coding style, have a look at clang-format's help `clang-format --help` and there look for '--style=' description.